# Calculate residual deviance from scikit-learn logistic regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

Is there any way to calculate residual deviance of a [scikit-learn logistic regression model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)? This is a standard output from R model summaries, but I couldn't find it any of sklearn's documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As suggested by @russell-richie, it should be `model.predict_proba`
2. Don't forget the argument `normalize=False` in function `metrics.log_loss()` to return the sum of the per-sample losses.

So to complete @ingo's answer, to obtain the model deviance with `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`, you can compute:

```
def deviance(X, y, model):
    return 2*metrics.log_loss(y, model.predict_proba(X), normalize=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can. Deviance is closely related to cross entropy, which is in `sklearn.metrics.log_loss`. Deviance is just 2*(loglikelihood_of_saturated_model - loglikelihood_of_fitted_model). Scikit learn can (without larger tweaks) only handle classification of individual instances, so that the log-likelihood of the saturated model is going to be zero. Cross entropy as returned by `log_loss` is the negative log-likelihood. Thus, the deviance is simply

```
def deviance(X, y, model):
    return 2*metrics.log_loss(y, model.predict_log_proba(X))
```

I know this is a very late answer, but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Should it be `model.predict_log_proba`, or just `.predict_proba`? The log_loss documentation indicates that the second argument `y_pred` should be probabilities...

Comment: Correct, the documentation is unspecific here. It should be `log_proba`.

Comment: The documentation states that the second parameter should be probabilites, not log(probabilities).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in scikit-learn but check out **statsmodels**, `GLMResults`([API](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html#statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python implementation of explained_deviance that implements the discussions from this thread: [Github code](https://github.com/RoshanRane/Deviance_explained)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax, expit
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier

# deviance function
def explained_deviance(y_true, y_pred_logits=None, y_pred_probas=None, 
                       returnloglikes=False):
    """Computes explained_deviance score to be comparable to explained_variance"""
    
    assert y_pred_logits is not None or y_pred_probas is not None, "Either the predicted probabilities \
(y_pred_probas) or the predicted logit values (y_pred_logits) should be provided. But neither of the two were provided."
    
    if y_pred_logits is not None and y_pred_probas is None:
        # check if binary or multiclass classification
        if y_pred_logits.ndim == 1: 
            y_pred_probas = expit(y_pred_logits)
        elif y_pred_logits.ndim == 2: 
            y_pred_probas = softmax(y_pred_logits)
        else: # invalid
            raise ValueError(f"logits passed seem to have incorrect shape of {y_pred_logits.shape}")
            
    if y_pred_probas.ndim == 1: y_pred_probas = np.stack([1-y_pred_probas, y_pred_probas], axis=-1)
    
    # compute a null model's predicted probability
    X_dummy = np.zeros(len(y_true))
    y_null_probas = DummyClassifier(strategy='prior').fit(X_dummy,y_true).predict_proba(X_dummy)
    #strategy : {"most_frequent", "prior", "stratified", "uniform",  "constant"}
    # suggestion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215317
    llf = -log_loss(y_true, y_pred_probas, normalize=False)
    llnull = -log_loss(y_true, y_null_probas, normalize=False)
    ### McFadden’s pseudo-R-squared: 1 - (llf / llnull)
    explained_deviance = 1 - (llf / llnull)
    ## Cox & Snell’s pseudo-R-squared: 1 - exp((llnull - llf)*(2/nobs))
    # explained_deviance = 1 - np.exp((llnull - llf) * (2 / len(y_pred_probas))) ## TODO, not implemented
    if returnloglikes:
        return explained_deviance, {'loglike_model':llf, 'loglike_null':llnull}
    else:
        return explained_deviance
```