# logistic regression residuals plot/distribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression, yellowbrick

I am trying to evaluate the logistic model with residual plot in `Python`.
I searched on the internet and cannot get the info.
It seems that we can calculate the `deviance residual` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215317/7651845).

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
def deviance(X_test, true, model):
    return 2*log_loss(y_true, model.predict_log_proba(X_test))
```

This returns a numeric value.

However, we can evaluate residuals plot when performing `GLM`....
It seems that there are no packages for `Python` to plot logistic regression residuals, pearson or deviance.

Moreover, I found a interesting package [`ResidualsPlot`](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/regressor/residuals.html). But I'm not sure whether it can be used for logistic regression.

Any suggestion for plotting residuals plot?

In addition, I also found a resource [here](https://medium.com/@emredjan/emulating-r-regression-plots-in-python-43741952c034), which is for `ols` rather than `logit`. It seems that the calculations of residuals are a little bit different.

Comment: My initial reaction is to say you could just take the difference of the true values and the values predicted by the regression (the score), and plot those, since they are, in fact, the residuals. You could plot these against the explanatory variables to look for issues. Is your question more about how to find the residuals, find relationships, or do the actual mechanics of the plotting?

Comment: I think the way you mentioned, the difference, is what `ResidualsPlot` do. However, my question is for logistic regression, it seems that there are `pearson residuals` and `deviance residuals`, how do I calculate these two and plot them in `Python`.

Comment: I'll go with my usual answer: think about what you're trying to do. If you want to do some forensics on the model, the residuals are great for exploring whether you have some unmodeled relationships. The basic residuals (the true minus the score) could be plotted against x1, x2, etc. to see if there are obvious patters (say, one of them should be entered with a quadratic). The more sophisticated residual formulas might be interesting, but do they actually get at what you want?

Comment: The more complex residual formulas, `pearson` or `deviance`, are good to use when modeling in logistic regression. Actually, I'm not sure whether it is good to solely use y_actual minus predicted.